# What is wrong with my code for a basic calculator?

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I'm trying to program a calculator, but I can't find the bug in my code. Here's my code:

```
  <html>
<head>
<title>*</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="number" placeholder="Enter a number" id="val1"><br>
times<br>
<input type="number" placeholder="Enter a number" id="val2"><br>
<input type="button" value="Calulate" onClick="myFunction()">
<script>
function myFunction(){
var val1 = document.getElementById(val1)value;
var val2 = document.getElementById(val2)value;
var result = val1*val2;
alert("The result " + result);
}
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If you know how, and want to, can you help me to make it a calculator for +,-,:,* etc all in one? Thank you very much!

Comment: Please describe the problem you have, what you expect your code to do, and what it does instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a dot(.), and the selector is wrong use "#id" for ids and ".class" for classes.

`var val1 = document.getElementById("#val1")`**`.`**`value;`

Comment: Thanks, but if I add the dots, the code still doesn't work...

Comment: @MoosMas check the selectors `document.getElementById("#val1")`

Comment: `getElementById()` does not require the `#`, only the value of the ID -- i.e `getElementById('val1')`.

Comment: @showdev Your absolutely right, I'm so used to jQuery that I didn't even realized it...